# Fuzzy Address Matching using Rapid Fuzz

Tags: python, python-3.x, fuzzy-logic

I am using [RapidFuzz](https://maxbachmann.github.io/RapidFuzz/index.html) for matching US Addresses from two separate datasets.

I was able to get the results that I was hoping for using the below code:

```
for address in EB_RATING_LIST:
    matches1.append(process.extractOne(address,CLAIMS_LIST, scorer = fuzz.ratio))
DAVE_EB_NO_DUPLICATES_ADDRESS['MATCHED_ADDRESS'] = matches1
```

But, I don't have a full confidence on the results I received. For example:

**10 Washington Street** has a 86% Match Ratio with: **102 Washington Street**

My Question is how can I proceed with Fuzzy matching at a more granular level?
Should I include the Zip Code, State as well for the Matching?

**EDIT 09/14/21**: I am concatenating Address, with City and State and then trying to match. I will share the results as soon as I get them.

**EDIT 09/15/21**: I did concatenate the Address, which is now having State and City name, along with Address and then tried Fuzzy Matching on it.

```
EXAMPLE: ***5805thAveStes323&416NewYorkNY   
(3505thAveNewYorkNY, 72.34042553191489, 9315)***
[Address that match the Most, Percentage of Matching, Index of the Address(From the table used for matching)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to answer this because I joined the community just today. To get into granular level, just tweek the scorer with different other ratios like token sort ratio or partial ratio or token set ratio, based on your use case. Just test two set of strings first with all these ratios and find which suits you. Hope this helps.
To know more click here(view in incognito mode if it asks for subscription) --> https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/all-about-rapidfuzz-string-similarity-and-matching-cd26fdc963d8